# Showing that a group is simple.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

> Given a non-commutative group of order $\mathrm{ord}(G)=343$. Prove that $G$ is a simple group.

So I have to show that the only normal subgroups are the trivial group and the group itself. But I don't know how to use the order of the group to show it. The non-abelian part is also not helping really.

Comment: $343 = 7^3$ might help.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? If the group is non-abelian, then the center is not all of $G$. But the center in a group with prime power order is always nontrivial.

Comment: A finite group whose order is a power of a prime greater than the first is never simple. It always has a non-trivial center by the modified class equation. Its center is therefore a non-identity normal subgroup, and is Abelian. If the whole group is Abelian, it certainly isn't simple as its order is not prime. Either way, the group can't be simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact $G$ is not simple! This holds in general. Because $|G|=p^n$ where $p$ is a prime and $n>1$ we have that $Z(G)\neq 1$. If $G$ is not abelian then $Z(G)\neq G$ and thus $G$ is not simple because $Z(G)$ is  normal in $G$.

In case now $G$ is abelian. Then $G=Z(G)$ and every subgroup of $G$ is normal. Let $g\neq 1$. 
If $\langle g \rangle \neq G$ then we are done because we found a non-trivial subgroup of $G$.

If $G=\langle g \rangle$ then $G$ is cyclic and let $H= \langle g^p \rangle$. We have that $1\neq H\lhd G$ because :

If $H=1$ then $g^p=1 \Rightarrow|G|=|\langle g \rangle |=p$ -contradiction.

If $G=H$ then $g\in \langle g^p \rangle  \Rightarrow g=g^{kp} \Rightarrow g^{kp-1}=1 \Rightarrow o(g) \mid kp-1 \Rightarrow p \mid kp-1 \Rightarrow p=1$ again a contradiction.

Comment: And of course an abelian group of order $p^n$ is also not simple.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen i just wrote it down:)